# Create Nagios Metric to Show Host CPU Usage

Tags: nagios

I want to create metric that show the current CPU Usage on a host.
Metric that I want is like on the Ganglia (gweb)
How I can build that?

Answer (score 3):

If the host is Linux/UNIX you could install NRPE on the monitored host, then use `check_nrpe` to remotely run the `check_cpu` plugin.

If the host is windows, you could install NC_Net on the monitored host, then use `check_nt` to query the CPU usage.

If the host is SNMP-capable, you could use `check_snmp` to query the CPU OID , either `1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.11.0` (NET-SNMP) or `1.3.6.1.4.1.9.2.1.58.0` (HOST-MIB)

If the host is a VMware guest, then you need to query the VirtualCentre.  Check on [monitoringexchange.org](http://monitoringexchange.org/) for the `check_vmware` plugin.

This will allow Nagios to alert based on CPU usage thresholds.  To obtain graphs and so on (as in Ganglia) you will need to add something like `pnp4nagios` to graph the perfstats.